# Check in one CVS & Check out another CVS

Tags: cvs

We have a CVS server, the same we are using for check-in & check-out for production only, I have got one idea to devide both like : one server is for check in , another server for check-out (like production CVS, QA CVS), is it possible?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is certainly possible. You should use [cvsup](http://www.cvsup.org/) to replicate the data from once server to another.

I used to manage development teams in 9 different locations in 5 different timezones. Various modules were shared between the groups. Each toplevel directory in the CVS repository was originating on one particular location and replicated to the other locations if it was used as a library in in that location's developement.

`cvsup` takes a little bit more to setup as it is written in module-3 (which you probably do not have installed and needs compiling), but that is worth the effort. Alternatively you can try [csup](https://bitbucket.org/mux/csup), which should be compatible, but I have not used that myself.

You also need to be aware that `cvsup` uses a pull model. Unless regular pulling is inexpensive (because you are on a local network), you want to have some mechanism like we had that notifies the check-out servers to do a pull, once something is committed to the check-in server.